# Oracle Apex Checkbox Group, disable item option

Tags: oracle-apex

It is possible to disable one option of checkbox group? I have created an *P100_CREATE_PT* item and disable one option using JavaScript:

```
const nodeList = document.querySelector("#P100_CREATE_PT_0");
if(nodeList) {
  nodeList.disabled = 'disabled';
  nodeList.checked = true;
}
```

But there is one problem: after page submit Checkbox Group item is null (undefined), but if disabled option is not set - item is not null, is okay. Where is problem?

In details: I have *P100_CREATE_PT* Checkbox Group Item with 3 options. In block JavaScript: Execute when Page Loads, I'm running JavaScript code, when page is loaded, first Checkbox Group option been disabled and checked - that what I need. When page submitted using button, Procesing runs the code: `APEX_ERROR.ADD_ERROR(p_message => :P110_CREATE_PT, p_display_location => APEX_ERROR.C_INLINE_IN_NOTIFICATION);` and showing error message with empty value (*P100_CREATE_PT*). And there doesn't matter how many options selected. If option is not disabled, *P100_CREATE_PT* value been not null.

Comment: That is very little information - not enough to help you. Can you describe *in detail* how you implemented your solution ?

Comment: I have P100_CREATE_PT Checkbox Group Item with 3 options. In block JavasCript: Execute when Page Loads, I'm running JavaScript code, when page is loaded, first Checkbox Group  option been disabled and checked - that what I need. When page submitted using button, Procesing runs the code: APEX_ERROR.ADD_ERROR(p_message => :P110_CREATE_PT, p_display_location => APEX_ERROR.C_INLINE_IN_NOTIFICATION); and showing error message with empty value (P100_CREATE_PT). And there doesn't matter how many options selected. If option is not disabled, P100_CREATE_PT value been not null.

Comment: Going forward please update your question with additional information instead of putting it in a comment. I'm able to reproduce your issue but I can't give you a solution. I did notice that it works ok if it is not the 1st value that is disabled.

Comment: Thank you. I found workaround with "nodeList.setAttribute('onclick','return false;')", but I don't like it. I think there is a bug with disabled attribute.

Comment: check my answer - that might be a cleaner workaround

Comment: This should be fixed in 22.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that this doesn't work if the disabled value is the first checkbox. On page submit it does not set the value of the checkbox.

However the value is sent correctly in an on-change dynamic action.
So a workaround is to set a hidden item on change of the checkbox and use that in the page submit.